# how use two getIntent in activity?

Tags: android

I need to get data from two activity by get intent but is not work.

this activiy1:

```js
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long viewId) {

                TextView idTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
                TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                TextView descTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);

                String id = idTextView.getText().toString();
                String title = titleTextView.getText().toString();
                String desc = descTextView.getText().toString();

                Intent modify_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShowDat.class);
                modify_intent.putExtra("title1", title);
                modify_intent.putExtra("desc1", desc);
                modify_intent.putExtra("id1", id);

                startActivity(modify_intent);
            }
        });
```

and this activity2:

```js
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long viewId) {

                TextView idTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
                TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                TextView descTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);

                String id = idTextView.getText().toString();
                String title = titleTextView.getText().toString();
                String desc = descTextView.getText().toString();

                Intent modify_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShowDat.class);
                modify_intent.putExtra("title2", title);
                modify_intent.putExtra("desc2", desc);
                modify_intent.putExtra("id2", id);

                startActivity(modify_intent);
            }
        });
```

and this activity than receive data:

```js
        TextView idTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView descTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desc);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent != null) {
            intent = getIntent();
            String id = intent.getStringExtra("id1");
            String name = intent.getStringExtra("title1");
            String desc = intent.getStringExtra("desc1");

            try {
                _id = Long.parseLong(id);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                _id = 0; // your default value
            }

            idTextView.setText(id);
            titleTextView.setText(name);
            descTextView.setText(desc);
        }
        else {

            intent = getIntent();
            String id = intent.getStringExtra("id2");
            String name = intent.getStringExtra("title2");
            String desc = intent.getStringExtra("desc2");

            try {
                _id = Long.parseLong(id);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                _id = 0; // your default value
            }

            idTextView.setText(id);
            titleTextView.setText(name);
            descTextView.setText(desc);
        }
```

i try to use this code but like above code, just on put extra receive and other not work:

```js
        TextView idTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView descTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desc);

      Intent intent = getIntent();
      if(getIntent() !=null) {
                    
            String id = intent.getStringExtra("id1");
            String name = intent.getStringExtra("title1");
            String desc = intent.getStringExtra("desc1");

            try {
                _id = Long.parseLong(id);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                _id = 0; // your default value
            }

            idTextView.setText(id);
            titleTextView.setText(name);
            descTextView.setText(desc);
        }
        else {
            String id = intent.getStringExtra("id2");
            String name = intent.getStringExtra("title2");
            String desc = intent.getStringExtra("desc2");

            try {
                _id = Long.parseLong(id);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                _id = 0; // your default value
            }

            idTextView.setText(id);
            titleTextView.setText(name);
            descTextView.setText(desc);
        }
```

please help.

Comment: Have you tried `getIntent().getExtras().getString()` as well as `getIntent().getStringExtra()` ?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to check like this

```
    if(getIntent().hasExtra("key_1"))
    {
       String data = getIntent().getString("key_1");
    }
    else if(getIntent().hasExtra("key_2"))
    {
       String msg = getIntent().getString("key_2");
    }
    ......
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with two way.

1)`if(getIntent().hasExtra("your_key")`) and

2) use same key in two activities for passing data

like `modify_intent.putExtra("same_key", title);`